# Redirected output of "hg status" to a file lacks newlines?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, version-control, mercurial

In IntelliJ Idea, I'm trying to write a changeset to a .txt file using this command:

```
hg status > status.txt
```

The status.txt file will be shared with my supervisor for review.

The command works, and the changeset is written, but no newline characters are added, so I'm getting **this actual output in the file:**

```
A file1A file2A file3R file4R file5
```

As opposed to **this expected output:**

```
A file1
A file2
A file3
R file4
R file5
```

Is there any way to format the output to be more readable?

Comment: Are you looking at the file in notepad? I believe Mercurial is using Unix newlines but you're using a tool that expects Windows newlines.

Comment: @JordiGutiérrezHermoso I agree. I tried it and opened in Notepad++ which identifies it as Unix line endings.

Answer (score 1):

The two respondents were correct. Mercurial writes Unix newline characters into the output file. If you open the output file in MS Word or Notepad, you will see a jumble of text.

However, if you open it in a text editor like Notepad++, you will see a better-organized format of the output text.